# Referencing properties from Method

Tags: c#

I have the following method

```
 public void ExportMessageContentToCsv()
        {
            var exprotedMessageBody = SelectedMessageBody;
}
```

SelectedMessageBody is of type (SequoiaToolbox2014MvvM.Domain.Impl.ActionLog)(SelectedMessageBody))

When I call the method I can see a list of properties (see screen shot). The problem is I need to reference the individual properties; MessageBody, Gateway, Direction, etc. but can figure out how to go about it as everything I try does not expose these properties. The end game here is to export  the data stored in the MessageBody to a CSV file but until I can reference it I cant - thanks

[image: SelectedMessageBody properties]

Comment: What is the tpe of `SelectedMessageBody`? It should also be visible in the debugger.

Comment: Its of type Object; public object SelectedMessageBody { get; set; }

Comment: If it is type Object, then you need to cast it back to (SequoiaToolbox2014MvvM.Domain.Impl.ActionLog) in order to access the properties.

Comment: Looking at this in more details the type is; object{SequoiaToolbox2014MvvM.Domain.Impl.ActionLog}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to cast that value back into its original type, as an object type does not have those properties that you are looking for.

```
var exprotedMessageBody = SelectedMessageBody as SequoiaToolbox2014MvvM.Domain.Impl.ActionLog;
```

You might also look at changing the property to be of the original type, instead of object. If there is any possibility of this property not containing an "ActionLog" then check to ensure that `exprotedMessageBody != null` before using it.